# How to force FFMpeg not to change keyframe sequence

Tags: ffmpeg

My problem is to encode an input video (x264) using FFMpeg with the same keyframe sequence and save the output video. For example, if the keyframes of the input video are 1, 5, 13, 35, ..., then the keyframes of the output video should be the same as 1, 5, 13, 35, ... Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The below should work.

**#1** Segment input file

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f segment -segment_time 0.01 -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 in%d.ts
```

This should create segments each 1 GOP long i.e. having one keyframe, at the start.

**#2** Encode segments with a very high minimum keyframe interval.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i in4.ts -c:v libx264 -keyint_min 65535 out4.ts
```

**#3** Stitch `out` segments together

e..g with concat demuxer

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy -absf aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

where list.txt is

```
file 'out1.ts'
file 'out2.ts'
file 'out3.ts'
file 'out4.ts'
...
```